# what is the preg_match condition to ensure the first digit is a number 7?

Tags: php

For e.g.

```
if(preg_match("/[^0-9]/",$number_from)){
   $error_message .= 'Please Check and try again.<br />';
}
```

is to only ensure numbers are entered for the string.

But what is the condition to ensure the first number can only be a number "7", or else the above error message will show?

Sorry im new to PHP.

Comment: Try `/^[7]/` and see if it works ?

Comment: `/^7\d+$/` => string starting with 7 and with digits only.

Comment: If you want to ensure that the first character is any particular character, just match that character literally in the regexp. Should be obvious.

Comment: if(preg_match("/^7\d+$/",$number_from)){  -- does not seem to do anything

Comment: actually i used /^[7]/ and this gives an error everytime i enter 7 infront of the string, i want the exact opposite: an error when a 7 is not entered in front

Comment: You two shouldn't repost the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272741/preg-match-condition-to-ensure-the-first-character-of-string-does-not-meet-the-c

Comment: @SharlineSivanathan simply use `if( !preg_match( ... ) )`

Answer (score 1):

The very simple regular expression suggested in comment:

```
/^7\d+$/
```

will match every string containing only digits and starting with 7 that, if I understand your question, is your validated string.

To check for errors, you can use this syntax:

```
if( ! preg_match( "/^7\d+$/", $number_from ) )
{
   $error_message .= 'Please Check and try again.<br />';
}
```

The exclamation point `!` in front of `preg_match` is a negation. It means: “If not match”.

Comment: I was just about to post a community wiki (no rep gain) and quoting you and stating I wasn't going to take credit for it. *lol* oh, well. I closed their other question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I write it to mark other question as duplicated

Comment: I saw that; got 2 upvotes for it ;-) It has been closed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272741/preg-match-condition-to-ensure-the-first-character-of-string-does-not-meet-the-c

Comment: I'm wondering if they're even echoing `$error_message`. and OP has a pretty bad track record.

Comment: We'll know soon. By a different nickname, maybe.

Comment: forse mi amico, *forse*. ma, no lo so. ;-)

Comment: Oh, this is rich. [See what the OP left in their other question for me...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272741/preg-match-condition-to-ensure-the-first-character-of-string-does-not-meet-the-c?noredirect=1#comment60172825_36272741) *lol*

Comment: I do not believe it... :D :D :D